# How to convert the ext 3 file system of hard disk to ntfs and install Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs

In my laptop earlier I had Windows 7 32-bit installed and then I had formatted the complete hard disk to ext 3 and installed Linux Ubuntu. Now I want to install Windows 7, but when I try to install windows 7 the boot-able Windows 7 USB stick, the installer could not recognize my hard disk. How can I solve this problem and install Windows? Should I format the whole hard disk and convert it to NTFS using GParted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of what filesystems you currently have on your hard disk the Windows installer should still see the hard disk (ext partitions be labeled unknown). If the installer isn't seeing any hard drive at all then it's probably down to missing IDE Controller drivers.

Look for RAID/F6/IDE Controller drivers on your laptop manufacturer's support page for that specific laptop.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2101&DwnldID=23060&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Rapid+Storage+Technology+(Intel%C2%AE+RST)&lang=eng

Go to the above link and download the "f6flpy-x86.zip" drivers (second row) and extract those files on to a USB.

Comment: Presently Ubuntu os is running on my system.

Comment: @user2416657 - I would agree with Robula.  Windows should at least see the hdd.  The fact it does not means there is something else going on.

Comment: If you're looking to install Windows side-by-side your Ubuntu installation that would be a little tricky. It's actually easier to start with Windows and then install Ubuntu (that way you don't lose the GRUB bootloader). If you installed Windows now, you'd probably lose GRUB and therefore wouldn't be able to boot back into Ubuntu. What is it you want to do?

Comment: If only take the literal question, he wants to install Windows 7 over Ubuntu, but as you point out he might want to do a dual-boot.

Comment: i want to uninstall ubuntu completely and instal windows 7

Comment: Okay. If you can't see the hard drive in Windows Setup then you need to do as I explained in my answer: Find the IDE driver for your laptop, put it on a USB stick then at the Windows Setup screen you must click the "Load Driver" text and select the driver files. As shown here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/97441

Comment: If it helps, if you give me the make and model of your laptop I will try and point you in the right direction of the driver.

Comment: Country : India

Comment: Remove the Serial Number, you shouldn't really give that out. The Product name is enough. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11931/discussion-between-robula-and-user2416657)